# css align right and left at the same time

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a problem with displaying [this(check this picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWHtj.png)
I have a link on the left and icons with words under it on the right. What is the right way to display it? and how can I display the words under the icons? I need help with it. Please check the attached picture to see how I need it to look.

```html
<div class="back-to-listing-clinic">  
  <div> 
    <a> < back </a>
  </div>
  <div class="right-icons-part">
    <img class="clinic-top-icons"src="./assets/images/icons/forum.png"> 
    <img class="clinic-top-icons" src="./assets/images/icons/forum.png"> 
    <img class="clinic-top-icons" src="./assets/images/icons/forum.png"> 
  </div>
  <div> 
    <p> Icon1 </p>
    <p> Icon2 </p>
    <p> Icon3 </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the words in your HTML. It might help to create a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate.

Comment: @showdev I have added it

Answer (score 0):

There's a dozen ways to do this. I replaced your images with icons for demonstration purposes.

This method just sets the "left and right" parts to `display: inline-block` to place them next to each other, and then sets `float: right` on the right hand ones to separate them.

I'd consider using a CSS Framework of some kind instead - but this would be a simple way to do it with what you have.

**No Framework:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.back-to-listing-clinic > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.right-icons-part {
  float: right;
}

.right-icons-part:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  height: 0px;
}

.right-icons-part a {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
<div class="back-to-listing-clinic">  
  <div class="left"> 
    <a> &lt; back </a>
  </div>
  <div class="right-icons-part">
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i><br />Icon 1</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment"></i><br />Icon 2</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-comments"></i><br />Icon 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Super simple [Ungrid](http://chrisnager.com/ungrid/) framework**

```css
@media (min-width: 30em) {
    .row { width: 100%; display: table; table-layout: fixed; }
    .col { display: table-cell; }
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.right-icons-part a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
<div class="row back-to-listing-clinic">  
  <div class="col left"> 
    <a> &lt; back </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col right right-icons-part">
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i><br />Icon 1</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment"></i><br />Icon 2</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-comments"></i><br />Icon 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```